# How to convert output of file_get_contents into an array when sections of the file is split by new lines?

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

I have a changelog I am getting with [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) that is always in this format:

```
*** Product Name Changelog ***

2020-12-25 - version 1.0.2
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text

2020-12-20 - version 1.0.1
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text

2020-12-15 - version 1.0.0
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
```

I would like to get this into an array in like this:

```
array(
    '1.0.2' => array(
        'date' => '2020-12-25',
        'entry' => '[the bullet html]'
    ),
    '1.0.1' => array(
        'date' => '2020-12-20',
        'entry' => '[the bullet html]'
    ),
    '1.0.0' => array(
        'date' => '2020-12-15',
        'entry' => '[the bullet html]'
    )
)
```

I have attempted this but have only really found a way to extract the latest version using this:

```
<?php function getVersion($str) {
    preg_match("/(?:version)\s*((?:[0-9]+\.?)+)/i", $str, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

echo 'latest version is: ' . getVersion($changelog); // gets latest version ?>
```

Is what I'm attempting to do possible? I suspect I need to split it up somehow by the blank lines between each version and then extra the data further from those parts?

Comment: There are several tasks. Create array, sort by date (DESC) and output first entry. How should the lines with * some text be inserted into [the bullet html]?

Comment: just each bullet on a new line, I was thinking this would be * some text<br>* some text<br>etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For explanations, see comments in the code.

```
$input = '*** Product Name Changelog ***

2020-12-25 - version 1.0.2
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text

2020-12-20 - version 1.0.1
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text

2020-12-15 - version 1.0.0
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text';

$lines = preg_split('/\R/',$input);  //lines -> array
$lines = array_slice($lines,2);  //remove title

$result = [];
$arr = [];
foreach($lines as $line){
  if( preg_match('/^(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)[\- ]+version ([\d.]+)/',$line,$match)){
    //date + version
    if(!empty($arr)) $result[] = $arr;
    $arr = [
      'date' => $match[1],
      'version' => $match[2],
      'entry' => ''
     ]; 
  }
  else {
    // some text
    $arr['entry'] .= $line.'<br>';
  }
}

//save last
if(!empty($arr)) $result[] = $arr;

//sort latest version
usort($result, function($a,$b){
  return version_compare($b['version'], $a['version']);
});

$latestVersion = $result[0];
var_dump($latestVersion);
```

Output:

```
array(3) { ["date"]=> string(10) "2020-12-25" ["version"]=> string(5) "1.0.2" ["entry"]=> string(79) "* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text
* Some text

" }
```